# Dynamic Email Subject and Body in Docusign Powerforms in c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, docusignapi

Team,Docusign ,

I am using Email and Direct Mode for Powerforms in C#.NET and sending documents for signing using powerforms links and appending all custom tags as query string 
for e.g.

```
//This is just an example, emails are sending perfectly.
demo.docusign?powerforms.aspx?id=axx-4545-a56s&Prospect_UserName={0}&Prospect_Email={1}&EnvelopeField_CompanyId={2}&EnvelopeField_StaffId={3}...
```

but I have a requirement where, I need to change Email Subject and Email body as per different type of companies.

For e.g. if a CompanyType: Member, then EmailSubject: "Memebers Need to Sign NDA", and Mail Body : "Dear Member, Please sign... large text"

If CompanyType :Prospect , then different wordings for Subject and Mail Body.

Right now , I have to hard code single mail wordings and bound to use same email subject and body for both types of company and I can't change it dynamically.

I don't want to create separate powerform templates again for mebertype and prospecttype and under each again one for EmailMode and another for DirectMode.

Do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to using the API directly.

Powerforms don't provide the capability you're requesting.

Comment: Larry, you haven't given example, how to achieve same thing using PowerForms in API direly?. Could you please share some code or any sample >

Comment: Ask another question. Include what you want to do and what you have tried so far. StackOverflow is not a code writing service. If you need help writing code, you can start with the recipes on the docusign.com site. If you need more help, then you can hire someone to help you.

Comment: I give you minus one.